# counting number of occurence in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm working on Mac and I have an Excel file with multiple sheets. In each one, I have a column that contains PDB IDs in the format (PDBID_chain_otherID). I would like to count the number of occurence of each PDBID and in which sheets it exists?

When looking for each PDBID, I would like to take only the first 4 letters and my research must be not case-sensitive.

For example: In one sheet, I have the entry 5vms.1.A - I would like to search for the number of occurence of 5vms in all the other sheets.

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How would this be returned to the User as potentially there will be multiple sheets where found? It would help to include an image of your data and desired outcome.

Comment: @pnuts: No not yet! I'm looking for some tricks on the internet

Comment: Look for `countif`

Comment: Thanks @Jerry. Yeah I'm trying to use countif but I have to check the occurence of 225 word (in column A) so I want something automatic. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Then a pivot table maybe. Insert a header of your choice in the first row, then you select the header+words, go to Insert > Pivot Table. Once you get the pivot table, drop the header in the 'Row Label' box, then drop it again in the values box (eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5O65.png).

Comment: @Jerry, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[calculate number of occurence of a character in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2mD6.png)

@QHrr, 
I simplified the file. Now I have one column with PDB idS (A1 in excel file) AND I would like to calculate the number of occurence of each entry and put the result in column B.

for example, how many time I have the entry 5vms?